# Spring Boot OAuth2 + JWT and UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, jwt, spring-oauth2

In my Spring Boot application I'm trying to configure Spring OAuth2 + JWT

This is my `OAuth2ServerConfig` config:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456");
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources           
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                .tokenServices(tokenService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/profile/*").authenticated()
                    .and().csrf()
                    .disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

}
```

This my `UserDetailsService` implementation:

```
@Service
public class DBUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " not found.");
        }

        Set<Permission> permissions = userService.getUserPermissions(user);
        return new DBUserDetails(user, permissions);
    }

}
```

This is `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private DBUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${social.postLogin.url}")
    private String postLoginUrl;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS
        // files.
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

        // Set a custom successHandler on the SocialAuthenticationFilter
        final SpringSocialConfigurer socialConfigurer = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        socialConfigurer.addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<SocialAuthenticationFilter>() {
            @Override
            public <O extends SocialAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O socialAuthenticationFilter) {
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setPostLoginUrl(postLoginUrl);
                return socialAuthenticationFilter;
            }
        });

        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        //Configures url based authorization
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //Anyone can access the urls
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("PERMISSION_READ_ACTUATOR_DATA")
        //Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain.
        .and()
            // apply the configuration from the socialConfigurer (adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter)
            .apply(socialConfigurer);

        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Configures the authentication manager bean which processes authentication
     * requests.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Right now I'm successfully able to issue JWT accessToken but when I try to use it, my existing logic fails with a following error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.domain.model.security.DBUserDetails
```

For a some reason, `DBUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` is not invoked after successful authentication based on JWT token and instead of having `DBUserDetails` in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` I have only a string with username like for example "admin"

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: As far as I see, nothing. Seems like principal is set correctly. And what more do you expect that `Authentication` object has?

Comment: I'm expecting DBUserDetails object (after DBUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername method invocation) like it was with pure OAuth2 configuration without JWT token

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After Spring source code debugging I have found a solution how to inject my `UserDetailsService` into the flow. In order to do this you have to modify `accessTokenConverter()` method:

```
@Autowired
private DBUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey("123");

    DefaultAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter userTokenConverter = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
    userTokenConverter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(userTokenConverter);

    converter.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);

    return converter;
}
```